# Memory leak problems

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management, valgrind

I am having some possible memory leaks (according to valgrind) and invalid reads. I was hoping someone could help me understand why they are happening.

First I am getting invalid read's and the trace leads up to me putting values into a stringstream. Here is the trace -

```
Thread 4:
Invalid read of size 4
    at 0x80586AB: TcpClient::updateServerAgent() (tcpclient.cpp:64)
    by 0x805CB15: ClientControl::update_server_thread(void*) (clientcontrol.cpp:49)
    by 0x4040E98: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
    by 0x43C873D: clone (clone.S:130)
   Address 0x4553290 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 52 free'd
    at 0x4025907: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
    by 0x804F0A0: main (main.cpp:191)
```

I'll post the blocks of code for these. `Main` -

```
        //make agent and set robot's agent
    Agent* agent = new Agent(g, robot, 'e');
    robot.setAgent(agent);

    //make initial start and goal positions
    Position start(1,1);
    Position end(1,1);
    agent->setPosition(start);
    agent->setGoal(end);

    //set initial path
    //Position goal = agent->getGoal();
    Path p = agent->traverse(agent->getGoal());
    agent->setPath(p);


    client.setIP(args[3]);
    u_client.setIP(args[3]);


    //launch the clients
    if(client.launchClient() && u_client.launch_client()) {


        cout<<"\nSuccessful Connection!";

        //set robot id
        agent->getRobot()->setID(args[4][0]);

        //set the agents
        client.setAgent(agent);
        u_client.setAgent(agent);

        //set client control's members
        cc.setClient(&client);
        cc.setUDP(&u_client);

        //go
        cc.control();

        robot.pauseSensorStream();
        delete agent;   //************LINE 191***************
    }   //end if successful connection
}   //end if client
```

ClientControl -

```
inline void ClientControl::update_server_thread_i() {
for(;;) {
    usleep(UPDATE_SERVER_TIME);
    myClient->updateServerAgent();  //***********LINE 49**************
}   //end while
}
```

updateSeverAgent -

```
void TcpClient::updateServerAgent() {

//hold message to get the length of it
std::stringstream messagelength;
//message is 1 prow pcol grow gcol sensorhigh sensorlow

//************LINE 64 IS THE NEXT LINE OF MESSAGELENGTH<<...*******************

messagelength<<"1 "<<myAgent->getPosition().getRow()<<" "<<myAgent->getPosition().getCol()<<" "<<myAgent->getGoal().getRow()<<" "<<myAgent->getGoal().getCol();
//make it into a string
std::string tempStrLen = messagelength.str();


int length_of_rest = 3;

//find number of digits in prow
while(isdigit(tempStrLen[length_of_rest]))
    length_of_rest++;

//****repeat that process a few times**

//create message to send to server
std::stringstream message;
message<<"@ "<<messagelength.str(); //*****note I don't get an issue here****

//std::cout<<"\nmessage: "<<message.str();

//send
int numSent = send(fd, message.str().c_str(), message.str().length(), 0);
}   //END UPDATESERVERAGENT
```

A possible leak I can't figure out has to do with either calling a thread's callback or something to do with creating stringstreams. I get a possible leak on each thread, but I'll just post the info on one. Here is the trace -

```
22 Bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 12
    at 0x402641D: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
    by 0x42579F7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
    by 0x805880C: TcpClient::updateServerAgent() (basic_string.tcc:138)
    by 0x805CB15: ClientControl::update_server_thread(void*) (clientcontrol.cpp:49)
    by 0x4040E98: start_thread (pthread_create.c:304)
    by 0x43C873T: clone (clone.S:130)
```

The updateServerAgent code is above with line 49 noted. I see the operator new in the trace, but I never have the new keyword in my updateServerAgent code. I can post the whole code if needed.

Another one with the same trace just different functions between `start_thread` and 
by `0x42579F7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)`

which are

```
by 0x805FD02: udpclient::communicate() (basic_string.tcc:138)
by 0x805CAE3: ClientControl::udp_comm_thread(void*) (clientcontrol.cpp:62)
```

The code is -

```
inline void ClientControl::udp_comm_thread_i() {
myUDP->communicate();  //*****LINE 62*******
 }
```

--

```
void udpclient::communicate() {

//message to send
std::ostringstream tosend;
//hold return value of sendto
int numSent;

while(1) {

    //sleep
    usleep(15000);

    //reset tosend
    tosend.str("");
    //grab sensor values
    Sensor_Packet temp = myAgent->getRobot()->getSensorValue(myAgent->getRobot()->getCurrentSensor());

    //put header onto tosend and concatenate the values
    tosend<<"@ "<<myAgent->getRobot()->getID()<<" "<<temp.values[1]<<" "<<temp.values[0];

    //send
    numSent = sendto(fd, tosend.str().c_str(), tosend.str().length(), 0, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen);
    if(numSent < 0)
        printf("\nError sending %m", errno);
    //else
        //  cout<<"\nUDP Sent: "<<tosend.str();
}   //end while
}   //END COMMUNICATE
```

If anyone could help me figure out/understand these possible leaks I would be very grateful.w

Comment: is this C ? changing the tag to C++

Comment: try splitting line 64 into multiple stream << foo; statements, on separate lines. That should give a clue which argument gives the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the memory leak: I wouldn't worry too much. It's only a possible leak and we have seen reports of leaks with strings too, which we couldn't explain, but that didn't lead to memory hogging.

About the invalid read: it's obvious that you still use the agent after it was deleted in main(). Agent is passed to client, but client was not noticed that agent was deleted; this can lead this sort of problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help. You were correct about the invalid read.